# Jest mock implementation doesnt have effect

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have thisnsimple jest test. When i run the test i always get undefined even tho i have declared a mock implementation.

```
import { service1 } from "./service";

jest.mock("./service", () => {
  return {
    service1: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return "default mock implementation";
    }),
  };
});

describe("Test mock service", () => {
  it("test1", () => {
    console.log(service1());
  });
});
```

**service**

```
const service1 = () => {
  return "default method1";
};

export { service1 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably resetting mocks is enabled by default in your project. Please check the thread here: [Jest mock/spy returns undefined even when set up](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9131#issuecomment-668790615)

If you are using `create-react-app` then you'll need to add to `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
  "resetMocks": false
}
```

Some more info here [Revert override of jest default `resetMocks`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9935#issuecomment-732971503)

Otherwise check settings in your `jest.config.js`.